# sudo command is not working on Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I have a linux Ubuntu laptop (16.4) that was not supporting any command starting from sudo and I have googled but not getting any solution because we don't know root user and password, so I am totally stuck.

For Example:  If I want to run any command it doesn't work, like:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And I get the error:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

How can I fix it?

I don't want to format machine right now.

Comment: Why is the command `sudo apt-get update` not working.. what is the error? When it asks for password what password do you type in..? You need to use the user's password, not the root password. root account is disabled on Ubuntu.

Comment: i have followed this link as well but not getting any solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set

Comment: How did you follow it.. the link says that you must reinstall and you say that you don't want to do that?

Comment: i have used just su command but we dont know  password for that  , we knows only user password , please let me guide, Thanks

Comment: Not all things Sir , just trying run su Command

Comment: You broke the permissions somehow as that topic you posted suggested, try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/471503).

Comment: @CaldeiraG , how to login as root (Log out as the current user, then log back in as root.) i have tried but not getting any option for root

Answer (score 0):

Try to change back the permissions for the `sudo` binary:

[Reboot into rescue/emergency mode](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

Execute the following command:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Boot back into normal mode. If that doesn't work and you still have problems with permissions, then you've broken your system and a simple fix for the sudo command won't fix anything - you'll need to **reinstall** your machine.

Comment: And as [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set#comment801473_471503) suggests: " that will fix sudo, but it isn't going to fix the dozens of other things that were broken."

Comment: Yup, exactly. But @CaldeiraG, we do not know yet how OP actually broke their system.. if it is done the same way in that thread, then yeah, this won't fix anything. But chances (although infinitely slim) are that they only broke sudo.

Comment: That is true. Just want to point out that for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

Searching on internet i found that to solve that technical issue You have to switch to ubuntu recovery mode:

mount -o remount,rw /

mount --all

chown root:root /urs/bin/sudo

chmod 4755 /urs/bin/sudo

restart

This also is useful information:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sudo-urs-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set

Comment: This is the exact same answer as mine? You don't really need to remount, it's already been mounted.

Answer (score 0):

solve sudo error

you should reinstall "sudo" command

for this do fallowing recipe:

---

1- **install "synaptic package manager"**

you can download it from :

https://pkgs.org/download/synaptic

or

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/synaptic/synaptic_0.84.3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

or

search in ubuntu **software update** app "synaptic package" and install it

image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI8WP.png)

---

**2- open app**

---

**3-** on top of page click on search box  and text "`sudo`"
now find the "`sudo`" in list > and click on solid square & on the opened square select on "**mark for reinstallation**" > then click on Apply on top of page
and install it

images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTc0s.png) &  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WowwG.png)

---

**4- open terminal and run "`sudo`" command**

you get :

> ```
> usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
> usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
> usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
>             [command]
> usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
>             prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
> usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
>             prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
> ```

so : the sudo is working now

---

enjoy it...

Answer (score 0):

If you still have your password. Try:

```bsh
su
```

It will prompt you for your password and make you the root.
Do as the command says,

```bsh
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

you should get your sudo back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).